# Dragging calendar items crashes Finder

Tags: macos, finder, mail.app, calendar

I try to export a calendar item as .ics file by dragging them into the Finder. The Finder immediately crashes. The calendar item has an unconfirmed participant.

When I try to drag the calendar item into an email, nothing happens.

For regular calendar items without external participants, both dragging into the Finder or into an email works just fine.

Any idea? Is this a known issue? (Running macOS 12.4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be reproduced by creating a new calendar item with a slash ("/") in the title. Submitted as FB10791870 to Apple.

It doesn't depend on having an unconfirmed participant.